# Can you add to an SSIS object variable, appending?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have an SSIS package that calls a Stored Proc to populate a variable object (full result set).

This is fine.

Now we have a need to call that same stored proc again but with different parameters.  So really two sets of data that we want stored all together in the same variable object.

If I populate it a second time, does it overwrite what was there, or append to it?

I do this

```
Execute SQL Task
ResultSet = Full result set
SQLStatement - executes the stored procedure etc.
Result Set 
Result Name = 0
Variable Name = User::Subscriptions
```

I want that to stay.  But want to have a second Execute SQL Task that does the exact same thing, just executes the same stored proc with a different parameter.  And I want the `User::Subscription` variable to hold the results of the 1st `Execute SQL Task` plus the 2nd `Execute SQL task`.  Is this possible?

Comment: What are you doing with the contents of the object variable. I always suggest doing all of the work in the database (i.e. insert the two SP results into a table and do the work there). If you're doing some script against the object then you probably have a data processing design which is more convoluted than it needs to be

Answer (score 0):

Adding another `Execute SQL Task` will overwrite first result set, you can achieve this using the following workaround:

In the `Execute SQL task` create a Temp table, Insert all result sets into it, select all recored from this temp table in your result set:

Your query will look like:

```
CREATE TABLE #TblTemp(Column1 varchar(50), .....)

INSERT INTO #TblTemp(Column1 varchar(50), .....)
EXEC Stored_Procedure_1

INSERT INTO #TblTemp(Column1 varchar(50), .....)
EXEC Stored_Procedure_2

SELECT * FROM #TblTemp
```